# How to add extra files to a Django project

Tags: python, django

I want to host a folder which has separate html, css, javascript and images to a Django project. These ARE NOT the Static files for the Django project itself, but products and resources that will be accessed by users and will have additional folders and files inserted regularly.

For example: www..com/Bookstore/MyBook/GiftedHands.epub/

How do I do this?

Comment: create a folder and serve files inside it using django. Declare a url then when request comes check the filename from url, get the file from your folder and return the file.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there any code example you could give?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, what you're talking about are media files.

Look at the [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root) and [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-url) settings.

Those allow you to manage use-uploaded files (through filefields or imagefields).

Comment: Hi, I think I did not explain well. What I wanted to do is to manage files that are outside the django project. I know I will have to register the folder on settings.py then declare a URL. Maybe you can show me how to do that.

Comment: How are those files managed? Through Django's admin interface or through an external service? And in that cas, what would the user need to do with them?

Comment: Let me elaborate.

I am working on a book project built with Django 1.9.8. I have built the whole system including templating. 

I have an external folder outside the django project that contain my books. The folder has other folders inside it that hosts the individual books. The books actually contain html and css properties. So if someone wants to read a book they end up opening a html tab. (seperate from Django's templating system)

I want users to be able to click the link of a book and it opens in another window, but still within the django project.

Comment: I would either do it in the MEDIA folder (follow the links in my answer), which would allow you to send the book's files through Django's interfaces (admin or custom form), or probably create a subdomain (like books.domain.com) containing those static files. The django project would just like to that subdomain's elements. That would make it quite easy to set up (serving static files directly with nginx should not be a problem) and easy to maintain (a simple folder or a git repository).